# Integration several Air Applications into a showcase

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

Is there a nice way to integrate several air apps into one Showcase Application, without having to modify the original Air App Code to fit into the Showcase ?

Without necessary modifcations it would be possible to easy update the containtng app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `WindowedApplication` cannot be loaded into another, they just don't designed for that. Each one manages `NativeWindow`, so it's not like usual SWF that can be nested. If your applications have some main control placed into Application, you can compose showcase from those controls - but not automatically.

Comment: That its not possible automatic I already guessed. To Remove the Windowed Application shouldn't be a problem. I only have to create some kind of genereal structure, to embed all my applications into the showcase then ?

Comment: Your applications have to be converted from WindowedApplications to UIComponent (VBox or Canvas, depending on their layout.) If you connect their event handlers (initialize, applicationComplete and others, if any) to new master, everything should work.

Comment: i am now trying to seperate all the Applications in to Modules seems to make sense, but unfortunalety its not really easy to have modules with on styles etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can load the swf files for each AIR app based on some configuration file(that points to each swf file) into a main AIR app. Are you looking for this sort of approach?

Comment: sounds like a beginning ;) In my bin-release i think i got the swf you are talking about. Now I have to find out how to integrate them.